# How to rename partner ledger report in odoo8?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Partner ledger report name is 'account.report_partnerledger.pdf' by default. I want to change it to customer name (eg: john.pdf if customer name is john). How to do this?

Comment: Please you need to be more specific.Edit you question and  add the available object values.

Comment: object value is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [report_custom_filename](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/8.0/report_custom_filename).

Go to `Settings > Actions > Reports` and search for `Partner Ledger`.

> > Fill in the `Download filename` field. This field is evaluated as jinja2 template with `objects` being a list of browse records of the records to print, and `o` the first record. If your model contains a name field, you might write something like `${o.name}_report.pdf` as filename.

Comment: I used ${o.name}_report.pdf but I got the file name as False_report.pdf

Comment: @Bhanukiran This mean that you report object has no field `name`.

Comment: @WaIR After making changes as suggested by my answer,problem got solved

Answer (score 1):

Possible through complex coding but thanks to odoo community we have one module named

## [report_custom_filename](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/blob/8.0/report_custom_filename)

which will let you do this by little configuration

Answer (score 0):

Install 'report_custom_filename' module and make the following changes in report_routes method

```
def report_routes(self, reportname, docids=None, converter=None, **data):
    cr, uid, context,registry = request.cr, request.uid, request.context,request.registry
    response = super(ReportController, self).report_routes(
        reportname, docids=docids, converter=converter, **data)
    if docids:
        docids = [int(i) for i in docids.split(',')]
    report_xml = http.request.session.model('ir.actions.report.xml')
    report_ids = report_xml.search(
        [('report_name', '=', reportname)])

    options_data = simplejson.loads(data['options'])
    partner_id = options_data.get('ids')
    for report in report_xml.browse(report_ids):
        if not report.download_filename:
            continue
        #objects = http.request.session.model(report.model).browse(docids or [])
        objects = request.registry[report.model].browse(cr, uid, partner_id, context=context)
        customer_name = str(objects.name)
        generated_filename = email_template.mako_template_env\
            .from_string(report.download_filename)\
            .render({
                'objects': objects,
                'o': customer_name,
                'object': objects[:1],
                'ext': report.report_type.replace('qweb-', ''),
            })
        response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = content_disposition(
            generated_filename)
    return response
```